# Why is Reactor's Mono.fromCompletionStage slower than a plain CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, project-reactor, completable-future

I have a simple piece of code that "processes" data in the background and, after every `nth` item, logs total time spent on the last `n` items:

```java
class BackgroundWorker implements AutoCloseable {
  private final ExecutorService thread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  private final int reportEvery;
  private int processed;
  private LocalTime begin;

  BackgroundWorker(int reportEvery) {
    this.reportEvery = reportEvery;
  }

  CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(int item) {
    var future = new CompletableFuture<Boolean>();
    thread.submit(() ->  {
      try {
        if (processed == 0) {
          begin = LocalTime.now();
        }
        if (++processed == reportEvery) {
          System.out.format("Processed %d items in %dms%n",
              processed, ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(begin, LocalTime.now()));
          processed = 0;
        }
        future.complete(true);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        future.complete(false);
      }
    });
    return future;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    thread.shutdownNow();
  }
}
```

Then I have a `Flux` that feeds data into the `BackgroundWorker`, counting the `CompletableFuture`s completed with success:

```java
Flux<Integer> numbers = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 100000).boxed());
try (var worker = new BackgroundWorker(10000)) {
  int successCount = numbers
      .map(worker::process)
      .map(future -> future.thenApply(success -> success ? 1 : 0))
      .reduce(
          CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0),
          (acc, curr) -> acc.thenCombine(curr, Integer::sum))
      .block()
      .join();

  System.out.println("Done; success: " + successCount);
}
```

And the same piece of code, but now using `Mono.fromCompletionStage` instead:

```java
int successCount = numbers
    .map(worker::process)
    .map(Mono::fromCompletionStage)
    .map(mono -> mono.map(success -> success ? 1 : 0))
    .reduce(
        Mono.just(0),
        (acc, curr) -> acc.zipWith(curr, Integer::sum))
    .block()
    .block();
```

The first one that uses futures will print something along the lines of:

```
Processed 10000 items in 48ms
Processed 10000 items in 17ms
Processed 10000 items in 10ms
Processed 10000 items in 8ms
Processed 10000 items in 9ms
Processed 10000 items in 5ms
Processed 10000 items in 5ms
Processed 10000 items in 4ms
Processed 10000 items in 3ms
Processed 10000 items in 4ms
Done; success: 100000
```

But the version using `Mono.fromCompletionStage` prints:

```
Processed 10000 items in 138ms
Processed 10000 items in 253ms
Processed 10000 items in 327ms
Processed 10000 items in 477ms
Processed 10000 items in 315ms
Processed 10000 items in 379ms
Processed 10000 items in 448ms
Processed 10000 items in 509ms
Processed 10000 items in 595ms
Processed 10000 items in 668ms
Done; success: 100000
```

Why does using `Mono` instead of `CompletableFuture` degrades performance so much?

Comment: Have you profiled the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the zipping of `Mono`s is what takes up the most time and impacts the execution somehow. Probably because zipping like that creates a new MonoZip instance each time.

But you don't have to use reduction and zipping at this point. It is more idiomatic to `flatMap` the monos, obtain a `Flux<Integer>` that you will reduce without creating intermediate garbage.

Also, since the futures are basically starting processing on creation, you could do an even simpler `concatMap` (less overhead, and having to wait for each mono's completion doesn't really matter at this point because all the futures are already running in the background anyway):

```
Flux<Integer> numbers = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 100_000).boxed());
try (BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(10000)) {
    int successCount = numbers
            .map(worker::process)
            .concatMap(future -> Mono.fromCompletionStage(future))
            .map(success -> success ? 1 : 0)
            .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
            .block();

    System.out.println("Done; success: " + successCount);
}
```

You can even shave a bit more of overhead by avoiding the mapping from boolean to int and doing that in the reduce:

```
.reduce(0, (acc, bool) -> bool ? acc + 1 : acc)
```

Comment: But folding with `CompletableFuture` also create new future instances, right? So I'm still curious as to why `MonoZip` instances have that overhead. That said, using `flatMap` improved performance, not to the same level as using just futures but fast enough, so this does answer my question.